# Fetch a value from the Output of a task and debug the message in Ansible Playbook

Tags: shell, scripting, ansible, yaml

I need to Fetch the ipv4Address value from the Below JSON Output using set_fact. Finally ending up with some errors. Could you please suggest me some best method.

JSON Output:

```
    "result_dns": {
      "ansible_facts": {
        "azure_dnsrecordset": [
            {
                "etag": "440922d5-b234-488a-8cbc-97b77f0fef8f",
                "id": "2",
                "name": "test2",
                "properties": {
                    "ARecords": [
                        {
                            "ipv4Address": "10.30.23.5"
                        }
                    ],
                    "TTL": 3600,
                    "fqdn": "test2.testzone.com."
                },
                "type": "Microsoft.Network/dnszones/A"
```

I am using the set_fact as below to retrieve ipv4Address.

```
    - name: name
      set_fact:
      host_name: "{{ result_dns.ansible_facts.azure_dnsrecordset map(attribute='ipv4Address') | list }}"
```

I am not able to filter the value by above method. Can you suggest me some best method to filter the Value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are getting snared by the fact that 'azure_dnsrecordset' contains a list of dictionaries. There is only one, but I guess the presumption is that there could in other conditions be multiple. This will do what you have asked, but once you have more than one record, you might find your requirements are more detailed than in this question:

```
# Presumes that you have a 'result_dns' variable set in Ansible containing the JSON
- set_fact:
    ip_s: "{{ ( ip_s | default([]) ) + [ item.1.ipv4Address ] }}"
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ result_dns.ansible_facts.azure_dnsrecordset }}"
    - properties.ARecords
- debug:
    msg: "{{ ip_s }}"
```

[with_subelements](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/subelements.html), extracts keys from a list of dictionaries.

This is just going to produce a list of IP addresses, which might not be useful in the case you have several record sets returned. If you do something like:

```
ip_s: "{{ ( ip_s | default([]) ) + [ { 'etag': item.0.etag, 'ip_address': item.1.ipv4Address } ] }}"
```

that will give you a list of dictionaries containing an 'etag' and 'ip_address' key, giving you a way to identify the recordsets they came from.

Hopefully enough to get you started.